# MONGO : How to update a field using value of another field

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection of people:

```
{
   name: Juan,
   age: 21
}
```

and now , I want to achieve the following:

```
{
   name: Juan,
   age: 21,
   name_reply:Juan
}
```

I have tried using:

```
db.people.updateMany(
    {"name_reply":null},
    [{$set:{name_reply:"$name"}}]
);
```

but the following appears.
**Expected type object but found array.**

How could I update a mongo field using the value of another field?

Comment: Do you know what version of MongoDB you're using? [Aggregation pipeline support in updateMany begins at version 4.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline)

Comment: 4.0 and I'm using cosmosdb

Comment: This is not possible yet but should have support for this very soon.

Answer (score 3):

```
  db.collection.update({
        "name_reply": null
    },
   [
    {
     "$set": {
        "name_reply": "$name"
     }
    }
  ],
   {
     multi: true
   })
```

**But indeed this is only for mongodb version >=4.2 where you can provide aggregation pipeline to the update query**

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PXEoMiBsZ0n)

for earlier versions you can check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

something like this could do the job most probably:

```
db.collection.find({"name_reply":null}).snapshot().forEach( 
              function (doc) { 
                 doc.name_reply = doc.name; 
                 db.collection.save(doc); 
               }
             );
```